# BitGo lost password

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes, bitcoin

a friend of mine lost her password for a BitGo account.  her "Key Card" contains her private key in the form (actual info redacted for security reasons):

> User Key:
>   {"iv":"IDMkr...UH4g0TBCofAcIg","v":1,"iter":10000,"ks":256,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"lI8k...vhX0","ct":"Kf...LOmgbn67w2CRYBhcXtX
>   0wdPF3D7ThCKaeZhTymin9hcMD5eL...AosmmvfA8npiDIHWgvdbHAk"}

and it's clear that the "ct" (ciphertext) was encrypted using AES 256 CCM.  I've found a module (https://github.com/spark/node-aes-ccm) that will help me decrypt the private key ("ct") but the docs for the module are not very helpful:

```
decrypt(key, iv, ciphertext, aad, auth_tag)

key, iv, plaintext, aad, and auth_tag are all Buffer objects. decrypt will return an object like the following:

{
  plaintext: Buffer,
  auth_ok: Boolean
}
```

so other than that the parameters are buffers, there's no description for them... however, it seems I've got everything I need except the key.  from reading the docs on a related module (https://github.com/xorbit/node-aes-gcm):

> key is a 16, 24 or 32-byte Buffer object containing the AES key used
>   for encryption

I gather this is the key with which the private key was encrypted, but where would I get that and how does it relate to the lost password?

any help greatly appreciated

*** Addendum I ***

my friend figured out the password so following Ben's advice below I thought to try it.  the code is straightforward:

```
var sjcl = require('sjcl-all');

var s = sjcl.decrypt("ThePassword", {
    "iv":"IDMkrTa5UH4g0TBCofAcIg",
    "v":"1",
    "iter":"10000",
    "ks":"256",
    "ts":"64",
    "mode":"ccm",
    "adata":"",
    "cipher":"aes",
    "salt":"lI8kABgvhX0",
    "ct":"KfJUrLOmgbn67w2CRYBhcXtX0wdPF3D7ThCKaeZhTymin9hcMD5eLHIUAosmmvfA8npiDIHWgvdbHAk"
    }
);
console.log(s);
```

but when I run it, it pukes with the exception below:

> /Users/ekkis/Development/decrypt/node_modules/sjcl-all/sjcl.js:66
>   c="{",d="";for(b in
>   a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(b))switch(b.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)||p(new
>   sjcl.exception.invalid("json encode: invalid property
>   name")),c+=d+'"'+b+'":',d=",",typeof a[b]){case "number":case
>   "boolean":c+=a[b];break;case
>   "string":c+='"'+escape(a[b])+'"';break;case
>   "object":c+='"'+sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(a[b],0)+'"';break;default:p(new
>   sjcl.exception.bug("json encode: unsupported type"))}return
>   c+"}"},decode:function(a){a=a.replace(/\s/g,"");a.match(/^{.*}$/)||p(new
>   sjcl.exception.invalid("json decode: this isn't json!"));
>
> TypeError: a.replace is not a function
>       at Object.decode (/Users/ekkis/Development/decrypt/node_modules/sjcl-all/sjcl.js:66:438)
>       at Object.decrypt (/Users/ekkis/Development/decrypt/node_modules/sjcl-all/sjcl.js:65:473)
>       at Object. (/Users/ekkis/Development/decrypt/buff.js:3:14)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)

so it complains that the json isn't json.  but it looks fine to me! any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Presumably if it was that trivial to decode this without the secret password, the entire security of the system would be non-existent. Presumably you missing the key is exactly what keeps it secure.

Answer (score 3):

This encrypted JSON blob is produced by the SJCL library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sjcl). A decryption would be done using sjcl.decrypt("password", json_blob). However, if your friend hasn't already been in touch with BitGo [support at bitgo.com], I recommend that route first.

Comment: Ben, thank you for replying.  she has been in touch with tech support but because her wallet is "old" (whatever that means) the password recovery system isn't available to her.  they've thus washed their hands off the issue and recommended her to some Dave guy that takes 20% to brute-force the password.  so rather than paying him, I thought I'd seek a little guidance and try to do it myself.  thanks for the reference to the decryption call.  I will give that a try and report back on success.  I've come across others with the same predicament

Comment: my friend couldn't wait for me to figure this out so she paid Dave to recover the password.  he discovered it was the password she thought it was.  so that was a very costly experience

Comment: I've added an addendum to my post, please see above

Answer (score 0):

You passed a json object directly. What you need to do is pass a JSON string, ex:

```js
let a = '{
  "iv": "IDMkrTa5UH4g0TBCofAcIg",
  "v": "1",
  "iter": "10000",
  "ks": "256",
  "ts": "64",
  "mode": "ccm",
  "adata": "",
  "cipher": "aes",
  "salt": "lI8kABgvhX0",
  "ct": "KfJUrLOmgbn67w2CRYBhcXtX0wdPF3D7ThCKaeZhTymin9hcMD5eLHIUAosmmvfA8npiDIHWgvdbHAk"
}'

var s = sjcl.decrypt("ThePassword", a);
```